Erlang/OTP "-doc" attribute throws error in compiler
Trying to document functions in an Erlang module but the compiler says my -doc attributes can't be after functions. Of course, they're placed after functions only where they are before other functions so I don't understand the error.
Here's the module:
-module(plb_ctl).
-moduledoc "Functions common to PLB services.".

-export([is_node_running/1, start_node/3]).

-define(ERL_CMD,   "erl -detached -noshell -name ~p -setcookie ~p").

-doc false.
log(Msg) -> io:format("~s~n", [Msg]).

-doc  "Returns `true` if node is running on localhost.".
-spec is_node_running(SName) -> true | false when
      SName :: string().

is_node_running(SName) ->
  SNames = element(2, net_adm:names()),
  lists:any(fun(E) -> string:equal(element(1, E), SName) end, SNames).

-doc  "Starts a detached node on localhost if it is not already running.".
-spec start_node(SName, Name, Cookie) -> ok | no_return() when
      SName  :: string(),
      Name   :: string(),
      Cookie :: string().

start_node(SName, Name, Cookie) ->
  Cmd = io_lib:format(?ERL_CMD, [Name, Cookie]),
  case is_node_running(SName) of
    true  -> log(SName ++ " already running"), ok;
    false -> case os:cmd(Cmd) of
      []  -> log(SName ++ " started"), ok;
      Msg -> throw({erl_cmd, io_lib:format("~s", [Msg])})
    end
  end.

Compiling generates errors where the -doc attributes appear:
plb_ctl.erl:11:2: attribute doc after function definitions
%   11| -doc  "Returns `true` if node is running on localhost.".
%     |  ^

plb_ctl.erl:19:2: attribute doc after function definitions
%   19| -doc  "Starts a detached node on localhost if it is not already running.".
%     |  ^

A review of the Erlang/OTP source reveals the -doc attribute used the same way but I can't make mine work. I was able to find the source of the message in erl_lint.erl but can't figure out how it's being called. For now, I'm forced to comment out the documentation.
Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting these errors.
